# Data from object not transmitted to ModelState

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to add to db an "Producer" object, which has an "Address" attribute. After adding the address to the object created, I get an error from the ModelState, because instead of the address from the created object, it receives NULL.

Why ModelState gets NULL on "Address" and how can I fix it?

Class:

```
public class Producer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The name is required.")]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Funds { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The address is required.")]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Method from controller:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Funds,AddressId,address")] Producer producer)
{
    Address address = db.Addresses.Find(producer.AddressId);
    producer.Address = address;
    address.IsFree = false;
    address.ProducerId = producer.Id;
    producer.Funds = 0;
    producer.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(address).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.Producers.Add(producer);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("ShowMyProducers");
    }  
    return View(producer);
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Producer</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nume</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Adresa (creeată anterior)</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                **@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AddressId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Addresses, "Value", "Text"), "selectează adresa", new { @class = "form-control" })**
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

[watch before checking if ModelState is valid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIhvP.jpg)